# Map numpy categorical data to a numpy vector

Tags: python, numpy

I am having a numpy array that is looking like:

```
my_arr = array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
   ...
   ...]
```

I want to return a vector that will contain for each vector of my_arr the index of entry with value one. How can I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use [`np.argmax()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) for that.

```
inds = np.argmax(my_arr, axis=1)
# array([4, 1, 3, 4, 0, 4, 1, 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

np.where(my_arr)[1]

Look at docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) to return an array of coordinates:

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 2, (5, 5))

print(arr)

[[0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0]]

res = np.argwhere(arr)

print(res)

array([[0, 2], [0, 3], ..., [4, 2], [4, 3]], dtype=int64)
```